# Web Security: Worst-Case Situation

Tags: python, security

I currently have built a system that checks user IP, browser, and a random-string cookie to determine if he is an admin.

In the worst case, someone steals my cookie, uses the same browser I do, and masks his IP to appear as mine. Is there another layer of security I should add onto my script to make it more secure?

EDIT: To clarify: my website accepts absolutely NO input from users. I'm just designing a back-end admin panel to make it easier to update database entries.

Comment: How does the cookie get set? Browser & IP address are both fairly easy to fake.

Comment: This doesn't look like a programming question to me.

Comment: My current system: if the user does not have a cookie, prompt for password. If password is correct, place cookie on computer. (If an attacker manages to just take the cookie from my admin computer, he bypasses the whole "prompt password" process because he has the cookie.

Comment: @Yongho: Well if you are still logged in and the attacker has the cookie, this would be session hijacking: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking If you log out, the cookie should be invalid. Upon a new login, a new cookie should be generated.

Comment: Read this: http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page and consider clarifying your question to match the specific threats identified there.

Comment: @tom, you cannot spoof tcp over the internet.  You have no clue what you are talking about.

Comment: You can mask your IP using a proxy, but you can't spoof a different one and still get information back.

Comment: Ah, I knew you could spoof your IP. Didn't realize you couldn't get information back. Either way, it's not something you should use for trusting information since an IP can be shared by multiple parties. @The Rook, Thanks for the dick response that provides no useful feedback.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Checking the browser is a complete and absolute waste of code.   There is no point in writing a secuirty system that is [trivial](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/59) for an attacker to bypass.  If the attacker obtains the session id via xss or sniffing the line then they will also have your "user-agent".

Checking the ip address will force the attacker to "ride" on the session with XSS+XHR or XSRF.  This is because the hijacked token will not work on his box.   Unfortunately this also causes problems for corporate networks which use outgoing load balancing between multiple ip addresses.

HTTPS is a **must** be used for the **entire** session.  At no point can your token be sent over HTTP.  This is clearly layed out in "Broken Authentication and Session Management" in [The OWASP Top 10 for 2010](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project),  which you absolutely must read if you are writing a session handler.

**Session id's must always time out.**  If they do not then this is called an immortal session,  which is a recognized vulnerability.

Further more i am concerned about the randomness of your token. Make sure your study how to properly generate a [cryptographic nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce). Make sure your random number generator is strong and seeded with information that an attacker cannot know.

I also suspect that you haven't taken XSS and XSRF into consideration.  It doesn't matter how strong you make your session in other areas if you leave a major vulnerability unchecked.   Make sure you scan your application using [a free xss scanner](http://www.acunetix.com/cross-site-scripting/scanner.htm) or the open source wapiti.   Keep in mind that no test will accurately detect XSRF and every single request in your application is vulnerable unless you specifically patch it.

Comment: Very very very good post, +1 for https, +1 for owasp top 10 mentioning, +1 for timeout, +2 for crypto nonces. This unfortunately adds up to 1 at SO :( ;)

Comment: @Henri  LOL,  I'm glad you agree with me :)

Answer (score 4):

The proper way to secure admin access is using [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Https).

There are two attacks against HTTPS:

1. [Trojan on your machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trojan_horse_(computing))
2. [Man-in-the-middle uses legitimate yet malicious certificates](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2010/04/man-in-the-midd_2.html)

Clearly (1) is the most likely.  But on the other hand, your Trojan is likely to be out after your bank details and such, and the attacker is not going to sieve through all your stuff to discover and explore your admin relationship with a website.

Clearly if the attacker is sophisticated as to go for (2) you are not in much of a position to prevail.

That's as small an attack surface as you can get.

Comment: +1 https,  make sure this used for the **entire session**  at no point can the token be sent over http.

Comment: You can do even better by using client certificates for authentication. Or if you want to do even better, client certificates with the private key stored on a smart-card. (that's how online banking and goverment services is handled in my country)

Comment: @Ants Aasma Client authenticated sessions are actually a 3rd attack against HTTPS, but I'm sure that'll get fixed soon

Comment: @Will, would you care to explain in what way are client authenticated sessions an attack against HTTPS.

Comment: @Will, thanks, I had missed that one. The good news is that the attack is quite limited and quite easy to work around.

Answer (score 1):

Https is a must, but you also have to come to terms with the fact that no site can be 100% secure.  The only other way for you to get a significant improvement in security is to have very short session timeouts and provide you users with hardware tokens, but even tokens can be stolen.

Answer (score 1):

THe one thing I miss besides everything that is mentioned is fixing "all other security problems".

- If you have a SQL injection, you're effort on the cookies is a waste of time.
- If you have a XSRF vuln, you're effort on the cookies is a waste of time.
- If you have XSS, ....
- If you have HPP, ...
- If you have ...., ....

You get the point.

If you really want to cover everything, I suggest you get the vulnerability landscape clear and build an attack tree (Bruce Schneier).